# How can I have token support in the field formatter class?

Tags: entities, tokens

I have a content type with, among other things, a status field and an image field.

I would like to have an image field with the field formatter class set to [node:field_status:entity:name] (non-alphanumeric characters replaced by underscores as part of token generation), such that the image CSS class varies, depending upon the status of the node.

Using the class, I could then use CSS to apply an overlay image like 'Open', 'In-Progress' or 'Closed', over the top of the image based on the class being 'Open', 'In_Progress' or 'Closed'.

Is this something that can be done?

I am happy to 'hack' a copy of the field formatter class to do the job if  this is not something that would likely end up in the core module.

Is there a different way I should use to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, you can extend the formatter class and add token support to it, like for example `LinkFormatter::viewElements()` does this for the link title. But for this simple task I would use the node template of the content type and add the class there to the attributes like the theme *Classy* does it for a lot of details by using the filter `|clean_class`.

Comment: I have cloned bartik theme so I can tweak CSS outside of core themes.
So you are suggesting I make a copy of `image.html.twig` from `core/themes/classy` and copy it into my cloned theme and tweak there?
In response to @kiamlaluno, I want the CSS class of the image to include the 'State', so in my CSS, I can say `.Open { border=red; }`, for example.

Comment: No, for node fields I would suggest the node template, I provided an example as answer.

Comment: Actually, CSS selectors being so powerful, it would not need to be the IMG that has the 'Open' class, anything within the node that is outside the IMG would do. Maybe at the node level, the 'Status' field would be available for interrogation and setting the div class there?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is why I would handle node fields always in a node template. CSS can deal with this.

Comment: Sorry, I am used to using phpbb style forums, I didn't even see your answer! Sorry for sounding ungrateful!

Comment: No, not at all. I think we agree on the node template. I've added the first comment to the answer. If this is the information you want you can mark it as accepted (we are not supposed to chat in the comments, so it's more about voting and accepting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can extend the formatter class and add token support to it, like for example [LinkFormatter::viewElements()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21link%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21LinkFormatter.php/function/LinkFormatter%3A%3AviewElements/8.4.x) does this for the link title. But for this simple task I would use the node template.

To add a node specific class you copy [node.html.twig](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/bartik/templates/node.html.twig) from the base theme to the template folder of your custom theme, add a name suggestion for the content type to the file name and add the class to the attributes:

*node--custom-content-type.html.twig*

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    'clearfix',
   'node--field-status-' ~ node.field_status.entity.name.value|clean_class, 
  ]
%}
{{ attach_library('classy/node') }}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
...
```